# Facebook like trying to access http: from https:

Tags: javascript, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, https

I am trying to implement Facebook like and share buttons for a page, However I get the following notification from the .js

> Blocked a frame with origin `"https://www.facebook.com"` from accessing
>   a frame with origin `"http://staticxx.facebook.com"`. The frame
>   requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed
>   has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

I am using the instructions from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#example

My code

```
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {

      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js._https = (window.location.protocol == "https:");
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fi_FI/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }
(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Link:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://my.local/site/my-test" data-width="100" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

I will need my data-href to be HTTPS:
I was hoping somebody could help me out with what to do?

Many thanks.

Comment: That comes from the Facebook SDK, nothing you can do about that.